# Attach image to layer with tracking mask

Tags: premiere, effects, adobe, tracking, mask

I have a two layers.

- First is the an image (PNG)
- Second is a video

And i want to "attach" first layer to region on the video and track that (just like mosaic effect with mask and tracking work).

How i can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are looking for [Motion Tracking](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/tracking-stabilizing-motion-cs5.html). Unfortunately, Premiere Pro doesn't have that capability. You'd have to set [keyframes for the animation manually](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/topics/animation-keyframes.html), which can be a pain if it needs to be accurate. If you need to do automated Motion Tracking, you could switch to After Effects which comes with that capability (see link above).